# How to permanently fix chmod changes to an app deployed on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, ssh, chmod

I just made a post yesterday - [How to solve "500 internal server error" on a deployed python app on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72341242/how-to-solve-500-internal-server-error-on-a-deployed-python-app-on-heroku)

And today I actually have discovered the problem. The program isn't missing, but instead program's access on Heroku has been denied. So, I just did a SSH to Heroku and chmod the exiftool and now it works fine.

But then comes an another problem. This chmod change is only temporary. After a few minutes, the error comes again and I have to do the chmod thing again to make it work.

Is there any way to permanently fix this?

Comment: `exiftool` is not available on Heroku by default. Where did it come from? Are you using a specific buildpack to get it? Have you committed a binary file to your repository? Something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular: "**Post the question and respond to feedback** After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!"

Comment: Yes, exiftool is not available on Heroku. Its an external tool that I downloaded on GitHub and added to the directory. Its a complete fork from the [original creator's tool on github](https://github.com/JoseTomasTocino/image-metadata-viewer) but his website seem to work fine but not mine. Its working after I `chmod +x` the exiftool, but it only works for a short period of time, so I just want it to make it permanent.

Comment: Make the file executable _locally_, then commit that change and redeploy. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/70897423/354577

Comment: I am using cmd to deploy and chmod doesn't work on cmd. Can you please advise me what to do?

Comment: @MartinSmith, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285462/354577

Comment: This is a self-duplicate of your earlier question: [How to solve "500 internal server error" on a deployed python app on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72341242/how-to-solve-500-internal-server-error-on-a-deployed-python-app-on-heroku)